# Add item to array nested within a map in DynamoDB using Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to add an item to a list that is nested within an another list of objects in DynamoDB. I am passing in `"userid" : "041c9004"` and `"author": "J.K Rowling"`. I would like to add the string "hermoine" to the `characters` list within the second item of the `books` list. The function first finds the index of the object for "J.K Rowling" within the books list. Then, it should use that index to insert the string to the correct characters list. However, this code is throwing an error.

The DynamoDB table looks like this. userid is the primary key:

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "author": "J.R.R. Tolkien",
      "characters": ["frodo","sam","bilbo"],
      "title": "Lord of the Rings"
    },
    {
      "author": "J.K Rowling",
      "characters": ["harry","ron"],
      "title": "Harry Potter"
    }
  ],
  "lastupdated": 1597690265,
  "userid": "041c9004"
}
```

Here is the Lambda function:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){

    var params = {
        TableName: 'Users',
        Key: {
            userid: event.userid
        }
    };

    docClient.get(params, function(err, data){
        if(err) {
            callback(err,null);
        } else {
            var indexOfAuthor = data.Item.books.findIndex(i => i.author === event.author);
            console.log('The index of the author is ' + indexOfAuthor);
            
            if (indexOfAuthor == -1) {
                callback(err, null);
            } else {
                let paramsadd =  {
                    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                        ":character": ["hermoine"]
                    },  
                    ExpressionAttributeNames : {
                        // this is likely where the issue is
                        "#attrName" : "books[" + indexOfAuthor + "].characters"
                    },
                    Key: {
                        userid: event.userid
                    },
                    TableName: 'Users',
                    UpdateExpression: "SET #attrName = list_append(#attrName, :character)",
                    ReturnValues:"ALL_NEW",
                };
        
                docClient.update(paramsadd, function(err,data){
                    if(err) {
                        callback(err, null);
                    }else{
                        callback(null, data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

This is the error being thrown:

```
ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"ValidationException","errorMessage":"The provided expression refers to an attribute that does not exist in the item","code":"ValidationException","message":"The provided expression refers to an attribute that does not exist in the item"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
    docClient.get(params, function(err, data){
        if(err) {
            callback(err,null);
        } else {
            var indexOfAuthor = data.Item.books.findIndex(i => i.author === event.author).toString();
            console.log('The index of the author is ' + indexOfAuthor);
            var attrnamval = `books[${indexOfAuthor}].characters` ;
            
            if (indexOfAuthor == -1) {
                callback(err, null);
            } else {
                let paramsadd =  {
                    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                        ":character": ["hermoine"]
                    },  
                    Key: {
                        userid: event.userid
                    },
                    TableName: 'Users',
                    UpdateExpression: `SET ${attrnamval} = list_append(${attrnamval}, :character)`,
                    ReturnValues:"ALL_NEW",
                };
        
                docClient.update(paramsadd, function(err,data){
                    if(err) {
                        callback(err, null);
                    }else{
                        callback(null, data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```